# generate "Tweet" to twitter direct from Android Application

Tags: android, twitter, android-intent

I am developing an Android mobile phone application
In it I would like to generate Twitter messages automatically without the need for any user intervention.
By using the "NORMAL" Twitter integration technique, the user is presented with the Twitter
Tweet entry screen, then has to click on the "Tweet" or "Send" button.

I wish to have my application send regular Tweets "In the background".

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see why not, you should be able to use the twitter API for this. You'll need to authenticate the user to post as them of course, but after that you should be able to post without their interaction.